# How to Block the Output of WriteString?

Tags: output-formatting, output, printing

I have an external package that uses the following function internally to print messages,

```
PrintOutput[x__] := WriteString[$Output, x];
```

I want to block all the print messages of the package but can't block them by the traditional way `Block[{Print}, .. ]` because the package is not using `Print[]` to print.

I don't understand the command `WriteString[]` well. I even tried `Block[{WriteString}, ..]` but it didn't work.

Is there any way to stop the above function `PrintOutput[]` from printing?

Comment: Does `Block[{WriteString=Identity},...]` or (perhaps better) `Block[{PrintOutput=Identity},...]` not work?

Comment: No, sorry it didn't work for the package. Is there any other brute force method to suppress print that is independent of the print statement used internally?

Comment: A brute force method is to Unprotect WriteString, and redefine it. Alternatively, you can try to redirect $Output to a file.

Comment: `Block[{PrintOutput=Identity},...]]` should work, but perhaps you need to fully qualify the name of PrintOutput with the package name. And even unprotect it if it is protected.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments. I retried it using `Block[{WriteString=Identity},..]`, and it's working now.